# update redux reducers after store initialization

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers

I am new to redux architecture, I have this basic doubt can we update the reducers list after creating the store using combinedReducer and createStore methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update the reducers and inject a new one asynchronously with [`replaceReducer`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#replaceReducer) api of Redux `store`.

> It is an advanced API. You might need this if your app implements code
>   splitting, and you want to load some of the reducers dynamically. You
>   might also need this if you implement a hot reloading mechanism for
>   Redux.

Take as example this [starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit)

In [createStore.js file](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/src/store/createStore.js) the `reducers` passed as arguments to the `createStore` method are the result of `makeRootReducers()`. Pay attention to the fact that no one async reducer have been passed to this function.

```
 // extract of src/store/createStore.js

import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import makeRootReducer from './reducers'


export default (initialState = {}, history) => {

// ...

  // ======================================================
  // Store Instantiation and HMR Setup
  // ======================================================
  const store = createStore(
    makeRootReducer(), // <------------- without arguments, it returns only the synchronously reducers 
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      ...enhancers
    )
  )
  store.asyncReducers = {}

  // ...
  }
```

In [reducers.js file](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/src/store/reducers.js):

- `makeRootReducer` function calls `combineReducers` with the default reducers
  needed for the startup (like `router` reducer) and other "asynchronously" reducers passed as arguments
- `injectReducer` is a function called for injecting new reducers on runtime. It call `replaceReducer` api on the store passing as argument a new list of reducers obtain through `makeRootReducer(async)` function

see below:

```
// src/store/reducers.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer as router } from 'react-router-redux'

export const makeRootReducer = (asyncReducers) => {
  return combineReducers({
    // Add sync reducers here
    router,
    ...asyncReducers
  })
}

export const injectReducer = (store, { key, reducer }) => {
  store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer
  store.replaceReducer(makeRootReducer(store.asyncReducers))
}

export default makeRootReducer
```

Finally, in the starter-kit the reducer is injected on route definition, like here:

```
// src/routes/Counter/index.js
import { injectReducer } from '../../store/reducers'

export default (store) => ({
  path: 'counter',
  /*  Async getComponent is only invoked when route matches   */
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    /*  Webpack - use 'require.ensure' to create a split point
        and embed an async module loader (jsonp) when bundling   */
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      /*  Webpack - use require callback to define
          dependencies for bundling   */
      const Counter = require('./containers/CounterContainer').default
      const reducer = require('./modules/counter').default

      /*  ----> HERE <---- */
      /*  Add the reducer to the store on key 'counter'  */
      injectReducer(store, { key: 'counter', reducer }) // <-------

      /*  Return getComponent   */
      cb(null, Counter)

    /* Webpack named bundle   */
    }, 'counter')
  }
```

This technique is helpful when you want split a large app and avoid to load all the reducers at the boot.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it fixed the problem.

Comment: @Sibeshkumar glad it help you!